# Asynctask with many images in Android app crash my app

Tags: image, android-asynctask

I have an app that connects to my server an gets URLs of images.

Using that URL, I build the bitmap.

If I have 3 or 4 images, nothing happens, but, if I have 10 or more, the AsyncTask crashes.

Comment: It would be good if you can share some of the code you wrote, or the Crash Log

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading images from URLs, I would suggest using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), it will probably solve some of your issues, it seems it might no be only because of AsyncTask.